# Parsing single-line C-style comments with Antlr

Tags: java, antlr

I wrote a grammar for a small language which understands C-style single line comments, eg.

```
  // this is a comment
```

Here is a fragment of the grammar I wrote for this language, using antlr v3.0.1

```
  SINGLELINE_COMMENT
:   '/' '/' (options {greedy=false;} : ~('\r' | '\n'))* ('\r' | '\n' )+ {$channel=HIDDEN;};

  WS      :      (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

This pretty much kind of works, except that when the comment is last in the script and there is no terminating NL/CR, I got an annoying  message from antlr (at runtime):

```
 line 1:20 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at character '<EOF>'
```

How can I get rid of this message? I tried adding `EOF` token to the `(..)+` expression but this does not work.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but what happens if make the newline optional, i.e. you change the `+` to a `?`? or maybe a `*`?

Comment: What about leaving out the greedy options (they seem only for the +), and change the plus to a question mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `greedy=...` option: you usually need it when you have `.*` or `.+` in your rule. And since you're already putting line break chars on the hidden channel in your `WS` rule, you can remove it from your `SINGLELINE_COMMENT`:

```
SINGLELINE_COMMENT
 : '//' ~('\r' | '\n')* {$channel=HIDDEN;}
 ;

WS 
 : (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;}
 ;
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, solving the "no terminating NL" issue would involve a lot of tortuous grammar changes to cater for this edge condition. It is always simpler to merely add a NL to the end of the input stream, meaning you can then be guaranteed to have a terminating NL and not worry about it in your grammar. UNIX is correct in this regard, and Windows is not.

Not the solution to your specific issue, but the way you originally coded the rule exposes this problem.